# Trying to update nested ArrayList within a for loop

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am new to java and while trying to solve a prompt I ran into an issue which I couldn't find an answer to possibly due to my lack of understanding of the nature of the problem. I have an ArrayList consisting of integers nested within another ArrayList. I can update my temporary list outside of the loop in the very same manner but not within the loop. When I print *mainList* I receive an empty ArrayList within *mainList* for every integer input.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();



        while(input.hasNextInt()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int n = input.nextInt();
                tempList.add(n);

            }
            mainList.add(tempList);
            tempList.clear();

        }
        System.out.println(mainList);

        input.close();

        int angleSum;


        for (ArrayList<Integer> integers : mainList) {

            //2 clockwise turns
            angleSum = 0;
            angleSum = angleSum + 720;

            //init values within nested <Int> ArrayLists
            int val1 = integers.get(0);
            int val2 = integers.get(1);
            int val3 = integers.get(2);
            int val4 = integers.get(3);

            //Continue until first number in Combination

            angleSum = angleSum + (9 * Math.abs(val1 - val2));



            //CounterClockwise turn
            angleSum = angleSum + 360;

            //Counter Clockwise until val3

            angleSum = angleSum + (360 - (9 * (39 - Math.abs(val2 - val3))));


            //Clockwise until val4
            angleSum = angleSum + (9 * Math.abs(val3 - val4));

            System.out.println(angleSum);

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `clear()` on `tempList`, you remove the contents on the instance of the list that you have just added to the `mainList`.

You have to create new instance instead so that existing items in `mainList` are not affected:

```java
// tempList.clear();  //! wrong
   tempList = new ArrayList<>();
```